# AWS CloudFormation showing failures: failed to create: [ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroupIngress, LegacyKubeManifestLambda ...]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks, eksctl

I created an EKS cluster using `eksctl`, now I want to integrate grafana with this EKS cluster, I am following : [Prepare an existing EKS cluster](https://aws-quickstart.github.io/quickstart-eks-grafana/#_deployment_steps), because my cluster was not created by quick start. After I `create stack`, I got some failures,

```
Amazon-EKS-FunctionStack-VLJAWNJJPSPRNESTED, failed.

Status reason
The following resource(s) failed to create: [ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroupIngress, LegacyKubeManifestLambda, KubeResourceLambda, LegacyKubeGetLambda].
```

for `[ LegacyKubeManifestLambda, KubeResourceLambda, LegacyKubeGetLambda ]`, the error showed something like this.

```
Resource handler returned message: "1 validation error detected: Value '[]' at 'vpcConfig.subnetIds' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 1024, Member must have length greater than or equal to 0, Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^subnet-[0-9a-z]*$] (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx)" (RequestToken: xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

for `[ClusterControlPlaneSecurityGroupIngress]`, showed something like this:

```
The security-group ID '' is malformed (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidGroupId.Malformed; Request ID: xxxx-xx-xx-x-x; Proxy: null)
```

Can anyone help me with it ? Thanks

Comment: You will have to look at each specific resource that failed, and look for the error message it is reporting

Comment: @Shane, thanks , I just updated my question with more insights.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I left vpcs and security group id blank when I created the stack. Even though it says optional, I still have to specify them.